# How to set time duration of a timer trigger in activiti after the process

Tags: activiti

I am working on a project and using activity to build a workflow.
Now I encountered a problem about setting the duration time of a timer trigger.

[image]

As in the image shows, in task A, the candidate user wants to set the time duration for next step, the intermediate catching event with a timer trigger, by himself. E.g., the initial time duration is 1 min, and it should be set as 2 min. How can I do that with java code?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the timer duration to an expression variable?
Seems this would  be the easiest solution based on your explanation of requirements.

Comment: Do you mean like this?   <timeEventDefinition> <timeDuration>${duration}</timeDuration></timeEventDefinition>

Comment: If so, I have another question. How can I pass this variable into the xml file from Java code?

Comment: Yes, you simply reference the variable as you surmised.
As for setting it from Java code, if you mean from a service delegate (JavaDelegate) then the execution context has a setVariable() method. If you are setting from an external application you can read from a queue/file/database in a service task or pre/post class.